# Cakephp 4 giving 403 error while using ajax

Tags: ajax, cakephp-4.x

I am trying to implement cascading drop down box in cakephp 4 using ajax.

I'm getting an 403 error has tried many solutions from google and stack overflow from htaccess till syntax error and logical error can anyone please help trying since long.

Here is my code:

**Add.php**

```
 <?php  echo $this->Form->control('groups',['options' => $groups],array('id'=>'GroupId'));
                        echo $this->Form->input('user_id',array('id'=>'UsersId'));
    ?>
         
    <?= $this->Form->button(__('Submit'),array('id'=>'post')) ?>
    <?= $this->Form->end() ?>
       
<?php echo $this->Html->script('//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js');?>
<script type="text/javascript" >
        $(document).ready(function(){

            $("#groups").change(function(){
                var deptid = $(this).val();
                //var path="<?php echo $this->Url->webroot ?>/Users/getbygroup";
                $.ajax({                    
                    url: '../Users/getbygroup',                 
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: deptid,
                    dataType: 'json',   
                    cache: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    
                    success:function(response){

                        var len = response.length;

                        $("#UserId").empty();
                        for( var i = 0; i<len; i++){
                            var id = response[i]['id'];
                            var name = response[i]['name'];

                            $("#UserId").append("<option value='"+id+"'>"+name+"</option>");

                        }
                    }
                });
            });

        });
    </script>
```

Add action in files controller:

```
public function add()
    
    {       
        $this->loadModel('Users');
        $this->loadModel('Groups');
        $this->set('groups', $this->Groups->find('list'));
        
        $result = $this->Users->find('all');  // returns query object
        $data = $result->toArray();  // converts query object to key value array 
        
        $file = $this->Files->newEmptyEntity();
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $file = $this->Files->patchEntity($file, $this->request->getData());
            if ($this->Files->save($file)) {
                $this->Flash->success(__('The file has been saved.'));

                return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
            }
            $this->Flash->error(__('The file could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
        $this->set(compact('file'));
    }
```

`getbygroup` function in users controller:

```
public function getbygroup() {
      $fname= $this->request->getData('deptid');
      
       $this->viewbuilder()->layout = 'ajax';
     
     $users = $this->Users->find('list', array(
          'conditions' => array('Users.group_id' => $fname),
          'recursive' => -1));
     $this->set('users', $users);
    
}
```

Comment: If the URL of the page that's running this is `/Files/add` (as it would be by default, unless you have some custom routing you're not showing), then `../Users/getbygroup` would be `/Files/Users/getbygroup`, which is almost certainly wrong. Try using `/Users/getbygroup` instead? Or to have it use Cake's routing to be flexible, `<?= \Cake\Routing\Router::url(['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'getbygroup']) ?>`.

Comment: Url is working fine.  This is the error http://localhost/etapal/Users/getbygroup 403 (Forbidden)

Comment: Maybe you have some sort of authentication that is being checked and failing? It seems clear that nothing in what you've shown us so far would result in a 403.